# In PHP, how do I express a string literal on multiple lines without the new lines appearing in the rendered text?

Tags: php, string, multiline

Sometimes in PHP when I need to assign a large string literal to a variable, I break the quoted string into multiple lines so it can be read without scrolling 300 characters to the right. My problem is that PHP includes the new-line in the actual string when it is rendered in the application. Is there any way to escape the new line or is there a better way of expressing a string literal on multiple lines? I'm aware that I could use concatenation, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Running on Debian if it matters.

Comment: How about using an IDE that can wrap text such as Eclipse?

Comment: @KaneWallmann Damn, I didn't even suspect this might be an IDE issue. Well I can't say I'm prepared to give up vim for eclipse, but this gives me a new path of investigation, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On large string i prefer to use the heredoc style, also you can see a couple alternatives in the [PHP Documentation about Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score -3):

The `str_replace('\n',"",$string);` command  replaces the newline. See [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Comment: and what if he actually wants to use a newline at some place?

Comment: That wouldn't even remove newline characters — it would remove the literal sequence backslash followed by `n`. (since the `\n` is in single quotes, it is not interpreted, and so it is replacing a literal `\n` rather than a newline)